# Is it possible to add a keyboard shortcut to Powershell?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

I've switched to Powershell after a couple of decades of bash, and after some configuring of my profile (and adding PSCX, openssl and a few other tools) I'm generally happy.

One thing I miss from bash:

```
mkdir some-very-long-dir-name
cd (hit ESC then hit _ on the keyboard)
```

Escape underscore is bash for 'last item on the previous command'. It's super useful - in this chase I didn't have to type out the very long directory name.

**Is it possible to add keyboard shortcuts to powershell? How?**

I'm using ConEmu as my terminal if that matters.

Comment: How does your example translate to a keyboard shortcut?  There are automatic variables in PS for doing something similar `$$` for last command, `$?` for last return, etc.

Comment: Using PSReadline? https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You should add the suggestion to use `$$` as an answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I feel like he's asking for something different and his example just wasn't very good.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 'Hit ESC _' literally means hit escape then hit underscore, on the keyboard. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @DavidBrabant Yes I'm using PSReadLine. It does a bunch of stuff but doesn't seem to implement this particular shortcut.

Comment: If that's your use-case, I haven't found a method that replicates that functionality in a native `PowerShell` console.  You may be able to replicate in `ConEmu`?  Alternatively, dig into `PSReadLine` as that's the main addition to the console that adds customization.

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1 - I've done exactly that and found it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short answer:

```
 Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key 'Escape,_' -Function YankLastArg
```

## Longer explanation:

Thanks to @davidbrabant and @TheIncorrigible1 for pointing to PSReadLine: it's not the answer itself, but understanding how PSReadLine works is the key to solving this.

Although `vi` is the default editor on every Linux distribution, bash's default is `emacs` editing mode. From [the bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-vi-Mode):

> In order to switch interactively between emacs and vi editing modes, use the ‘set -o emacs’ and ‘set -o vi’ commands (see The Set Builtin). The Readline default is emacs mode.

Which means **'escape underscore' comes from emacs.**

Oddly, PSReadLine, unlike bash, does't use emacs mode by default. From [the PSREADLine docs](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine#usage):

> To use Emacs key bindings, you can use:
>   Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Emacs

It's not very explicit, but that means another mode is default. Confirming that, running:

```
get-PSReadlineOption
```

Returns:

```
EditMode                               : Vi
```

So there are two solutions:

### Solution 1: change mode

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -EditMode Emacs
```

You can see the effect with `Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler` includes the standard escape underscore shortcut:

```
Escape,_         YankLastArg                   Copy the text of the last argument to the input
```

Escape underscore now works.

### Solution 2: add the shortcut to your existing mode

Instead of changing mode (it turns out I like vi keybindings!), you can also run:

```
 Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key 'Escape,_' -Function YankLastArg
```

To add it to your existing mode.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to your `ESC+_` solution, the `PowerShell` automatic variable `$$` contains the same information without the need for `PSReadLine` (pre-v5.0 or without the module installed).

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\'

...

PS C:\> $$

C:\
```

You can also capture the command used with the `$^` variable:

```
PS C:\> $^

get-childitem
```

Comment: Upvoted as this is useful for anyone who needs a fast way to to 'last item from last time'. Alas I have twenty years of typing 'escape underscore' embedded into my fingers, and I suspect a few other bash -> powershell users have the same!